# can't get test unit startup to work in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, testunit, minitest

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 (ruby -v yields :ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]), and I am trying to get this to work:

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestStartup < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def self.startup
    puts "startup"
  end
  def test1
    puts "in test1"
  end
end
```

when I run it, I get

```
Loaded suite test_startup
Started
in test1
.
Finished in 0.000395 seconds. 


1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I had a hard time finding documentation on this feature, other than scattered posts here on SO and the like.

And yes, I want to use this feature and not setup.

TIA

Comment: http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCase.html mentions that it is `def self.startup`, not `def startup`, so that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ruby 1.9.x bundles minitest not Test::Unit. Test::Unit bundled in Ruby 1.8.x had not been improved but unbundled Test::Unit (test-unit 2) will be improved actively.](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/)

So you must be using the Test::Unit gem? Is it perhaps an older version which doesn't support this feature?

Comment: I had test-unit installed, but since it my code wasn't doing what I wanted it to do, I tried uninstalling to see if that would help, but it made no difference.  So if it works in test-unit, how to I actually use test-unit and not test/unit?  When I use "require 'test-unit' (after installing the gem, test-unit), I get an error.

Comment: Nevermind, found the page that shows how to do it: gem "test-unit" (then) require 'test/unit'

Comment: @user119282: If your answer has been solved, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted when you're able to do so.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I had to apply user119282's solution of calling gem "test-unit" everywhere in my code that I required 'test/unit'.  Otherwise, if the first place the require code hit lacked the call to gem "test-unit", then it would still use the old code and not work.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 1.9.2 uses Minitest instead of Test::Unit by default, so it might be that this feature is missing from Minitest.

Comment: What you said looks to be true.

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer, otherwise I would have had to bug the person sitting next to me. Thanks!